# Why do selectors need to be chained to use flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I have this structure:

```css
.flex-container {
    border: solid 1px purple;
    display: flex;
}
.flex-container div {
    border: solid 1px red;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;

    height: 100px;
    
    
    flex: 1 1 0%;
}

.flex-container .first {
    
    border: solid 1px blue;
    flex: 3 1 0%;
    
}

.first {
    border: solid 1px orange;
    background-color: brown;
}

.second, .third {
    border: solid 1px green;
    flex: 1 1 0%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="first">
            First
        </div>
        <div class="second">
            Second
        </div>
        <div class="third">
            Third
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="first">Last</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Before I added .flexcontainer to the .flex-container .first {} selector, flex didn't apply the flex: 3 1 0%. But using the selector .first changes the background of the box, so it looks like it is selecting it correctly. Is there a reason that this happens? I'm just trying to see if I get the basics.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't related to flexbox, it's just how CSS works. Because you already had a `.flex-container div` rule with a `flex` property, it was overriding the `.flex-container` rule because it was more specific. You can read more about CSS specificity here: [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Personally, I recommend never using tag names in CSS selectors unless it's absolutely necessary. I prefer to give each element with unique styles its own class, so I can target that class in a short selector without having to worry about more specific selectors being around that might conflict with it. The [BEM](http://getbem.com/) (**B**lock **E**lement **M**odifier) CSS naming convention is useful for this approach.